# jQuery selector bug? composed selector vs. simple selector & find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, sizzle

Something is very awkward about my situation... i have something like this:

```
<div id="selector">
   <input type='radio' />
   <input type='radio' />
   <input type='radio' />
</div>
```

if I use `$("#selector input[type=radio]")` all three elements are found, but if I use `$("#selector").find("input[type=radio]")` or even `find("input")` only the first one is found.

Is this a bug in jQuery? Am I not using `find()` properly?

*Clarification* : I want to use find() to get all the inputs, but anything I try finds only the first one.

edit: i'm using jquery 1.3.2

Comment: Unlike many other JavaScript frameworks, jQuery does not fetch elements by ID when you do a search such as $('input'). You need to prefix the ID with #: $('#selector')

Comment: I fixed the example... it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is:

```
$("#selector > :radio")
```

As for why you're getting only one, I'd need to see the actual code that's being run because find() doesn't stop at one and will find all matches so it may be how you're using it afterwards that is the issue.

Comment: I was also trying this in the firebug console, and the two commands return different results: the compound selector returns all, the find() returns only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The two code fragments should return the same result.

Are you saying that when you run the following code, the first alert will show "3" and the second "1" ?

```
var a = $("#selector input[type=radio]");
var b = $("#selector").find("input[type=radio]");

alert(a.length);
alert(b.length);
```

Can you please verify?

Answer (score 0):

Try

$("#selector").find("input[type=radio]")

Comment: that's what i'm using, sorry for the bad example :)

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/whCHW/1/)

All the three returns the same result!

```
$(function() {
    console.log($("#selector input[type=radio]"));          // 3
    console.log($("#selector").find("input[type=radio]"));  // 3
    console.log($("#selector").find("input"));              // 3
});
```

Answer (score -3):

$("#selector").children("input[@type=radio]")

Comment: The @ to select attributes is no longer supported by jQuery