# Selector regression after upgrade to jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.3.2

I've recently upgraded an application from jQuery 1.2 to 1.3.2 - and we've found a rather strange regression.

For some html approximately like this (simplified a bit)

```
<div id="steps">
  <div class="step">
    <span>step #1</span>
    <div class="removeStep"> X </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <span>step #2</span>
    <div class="removeStep"> X </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We previously attached an event like so, for all the steps:

```
$("#steps").find(".removeStep").click(removeStepFunc)
```

Under 1.2 this would find all the steps, even ones we dynamically added.  Under 1.3 this only ever finds the first step.

This also doesn't work:

```
#("#steps .removeStep").click(removeStepFunc)
```

However, this does:

```
#("#steps).children().find(".removeStep").click(removeStepFunc)
```

I can obviously work around the issue, but It does make me a little nervous that perhaps there are other similar regressions affecting the application now we have upgraded, that will only present themselves in some cases when we have more then one element to match.

Also I see this other question, which I suspect might be the same issue?

[jQuery selector bug? composed selector vs. simple selector & find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969647/jquery-selector-bug-composed-selector-vs-simple-selector-find)

Comment: For me, jQuery 1.3.2 selects both .removeStep DIVs and attaches events to both (nightly Firefox build). In fact, all three selectors you detail above return both of those elements for me. What browser are you trying this in? Could you possibly have more than one element with the id "steps"?

Comment: Additionally - $(".removeStep") also only returns the first item... this is on FireFox 3.5.5

Comment: $('.removeStep') also returns both entries. Are you checking with console.log( $('.removeStep') ) to see that the elements are found, and that it's not something wrong with your click handler?

Comment: I've done some checking - "#steps" is definitely unique in the context of the page. Also I can change to locating #steps by assigning it a unique css class, and it still has the same issue i.e. $(".steps .removeStep") returns 1 item, instead of all matching items.

We do have ExtJS 3.03 in the mix as well, but I wouldn't think that would cause issues in this case.

Comment: Corey - I'm checking in firebug.  I'll see if I can extract a reproduction out of the application this evening... though my suspicions is that will work when divorced from the rest of the applications baggage.

Comment: I have had 0 issues like this with jQuery 1.3.2. Im going to bet its something with the interplay with ExtJS.

Comment: Made small test page. Shows correct behavior http://jsbin.com/alico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have now resolved this issue after stumbling across this post:

http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/ae61896a809f6cf0

The problems were were experiencing were caused by our use of an old version of the jQuery Validator plugin (v1.3) that was incompatible with jQuery 1.3.2.  The problem has been resolved now that we've updated it to v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
jQuery('#steps > .removeStep').click(removeStepFunc)
```

or

```
jQuery('#steps .step .removeStep').click(removeStepFunc)
```

step #1
     X 
  
  
    step #2
     X

**UPDATE**

What about something like this? (untested):

```
jQuery('#steps .removeStep').click( function() {
  jQuery(this).remove(jQuery(this).parent());
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either, here's the results of testing:

$("#steps > .removeStep") -> 0 matches
$("#steps > .step > .removeStep") -> 1 match
$("#steps div").find(".removeStep") -> 1 match
$("#steps .step .removeStep") -> 1 match
$(".step .removeStep") -> 1 match
$(".step").find(".removeStep") -> 1 match
$("#steps").children() -> 3 matches
$("#steps").children().find(".removeStep") -> 3 matches

I don't believe the problem is jQuery, so much as it is some other library (possibly ExtJS?) interfering with jQuery's normal behaviour.  This is a pretty fundamental part of jQuery :)

Comment: If you put an alert inside `jQuery('#steps .removeStep').click`, and that alert triggers, your jQuery works fine. For testing, you could remove ExtJS and see if that helps.